# JavaScript не могу правильно программировать форму

Tags: javascript, html, form

Помогите не выводит значение из `function s()` нужно чтобы вывел `"Good"` если в `<input>`-е допустимое количество букв:

HTML Код:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <label for="user">UserName
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user">
    </label>
    <label for="psw">Password
        <input type="password">
    </label>
    <label for="gender" id="sex">
        Male<input type="Radio" Name="Gender" Value="Male" id="male">
        Female<input type="Radio" Name="Gender" Value="Female" id="female">
    </label>
    <label for="selMALE">Прически у мужчин
        <select name="selMALE" id="selMALE" disabled>
            <option value="Британка">Британка</option>
            <option value="Бокс">Бокс</option>
            <option value="Полубокс">Полубокс</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label for="selFEMALE" >Прически у женщин
        <select name="selFEMALE" id="selFEMALE" disabled>
            <option value="Пикси">Пикси</option>
            <option value="Ассиметричная">Ассиметричная</option>
            <option value="Шапочка">Шапочка</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    <a href="function:submit()"><button>Submit</button></a>
</form>
```

JavaScript Код:

```
var f = document.getElementById("myForm");
var userLength = f.user.value.length;
function s(){
    if (userLength > 3 && userLength < 10) {
        return console.log("Good");
    } else {
        return console.log("Bad");
    }   
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помимо назначения `userLength` не там, где следует, Вашу функцию надо хотя бы вызвать :)

```js
function s() {
  var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
  if (user.length > 3 && user.length < 10) {
    console.log("Good");
  } else {
    console.log("Bad");
  }   
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="user" name="user">
<a href="javascript:s()"><button type="button">Submit</button></a>
```

Comment: у меня сново не работает

Comment: @ArmanGhazaryan аккуратно скопируйте к себе код и html из моего ответа

Comment: ОГООО спс большое

Comment: @ArmanGhazaryan На здоровье. Успехов в программировании!

Comment: спасибо и вам тоже ))